# Use values in a list as index values to create new multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I have an array here

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [7,8,9]])
```

And another array that represents column index values in A

```
Cols,rows = np.array([[0,1],[1,2]])
```

I then want use those column values to index array A to end up with an array that looks like

```
Cols_result = [[[1,2],[4,5],[7,8]],
               [[2,3],[5,6],[8,9]]]

Row_results = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],
               [[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]]
```

I tried using `np.take()` but could only get it to work properly index for row values not column values

Comment: maybe `np.take(A, np.array([[0,1],[1,2]]), axis=1).transpose(1,0,2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `numpy.take` with `numpy.swapaxes`:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
ind = np.array([[0,1],[1,2]])
```

Output for rows:

```
np.take(A, ind, 0)

array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],

       [[4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]])
```

Output for columns:

```
np.swapaxes(np.take(A, ind, 1), 0, 1)

array([[[1, 2],
        [4, 5],
        [7, 8]],

       [[2, 3],
        [5, 6],
        [8, 9]]])
```